# I cannot loop through a string in a function

Tags: python

I want to create a function that can take a positive integer n as input and return the sum of all that number's digit.

Below is my code:

```
def digit_sum(n): 
    string = str(n) 
    for number in string: 
        num = int(number) 
        total = 0  
        total += num  
    return total
```

but the error message is :
Your function fails on digit_sum(434). It returns 4 when it should return 11.

To my knowledge is that the for loop doesn't loop successfully. It only loops one time then return the value.

My questions are:

1. what' wrong with my code?
2. The reason I need to convert the number into string first is that integer cannot iterable?

Hope anyone could help me out.
Thanks!!

Comment: Just move the `total = 0` outside of your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting total equal to zero within the loop. What this means is each pass through it adopts the most recent value, o + num, which in the last digit of this string is 4. Instead, try this:

```
def digit_sum(n): 
    string = str(n) 
    total = 0 
    for number in string: 
        num = int(number)  
        total += num  
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are resetting the value of `total` back to `0` with each iteration of the loop. Move the initialization to above the loop, like this

```
def digit_sum(n): 
    string = str(n) 
    total = 0 
    for number in string: 
        num = int(number)  
        total += num  
    return total
```

Comment: Jinx, you owe me a beer!

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting `total` on each iteration. Move `total = 0` outside of the for loop.